# Cannot resolve symbol fsSerializer.TrySerialize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I imported "[Custom Quest - Quest System](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/custom-quest-quest-system-92594)" unity plugin into my Unity 2018.2.11f1 project. Then following two errors popped-up in `SaveGameJsonSerializer.cs`.

```cs
try
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter ( stream, encoding );
    fsSerializer serializer = new fsSerializer ();
    fsData data = new fsData ();
    serializer.TrySerialize ( obj, out data );
    writer.Write ( fsJsonPrinter.CompressedJson ( data ) );
    writer.Dispose ();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    Debug.LogException ( ex );
}
```

> fsSerializer.TrySerialize: Cannot resolve symbol 'TrySerialize'
>
> fsJsonPrinter.CompressedJson: Cannot resolve symbol 'TrySerialize'

What incompatibility causes this issue? How can I fix it? Thanks

#### Edit:

Here are the overloads of `TrySerialize` present in `fsSerializer`:

```cs
public fsResult TrySerialize<T>(T instance, out fsData data);
public fsResult TryDeserialize<T>(fsData data, ref T instance);
public fsResult TrySerialize(Type storageType, object instance, out fsData data);
public fsResult TrySerialize(Type storageType, Type overrideConverterType, object instance, out fsData data);
```

Comment: Can you locate the `fsSerializer` class? Which is unfortunately badly named (does not follow convention), but does it have the indicated methods?

Comment: Updated the question. I think Unity's built-in FullSerializer is incompatible with this code. Can you tell me a way to disable built in libraries

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is (or rather, why its a problem). My best advice is to reach out to the person that made the quest system.

Comment: Could you show us your complete code? I looked into the Asset and imported it into a new empty project. There is no Script called `SaveGameJsonSerialzer` and I don't get any error.